# dojox.mobile.ListItem OnClick not working

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, dom-events, dojox.mobile

I am trying to call a function when a `ListItem` is clicked in a dojo mobile application.

This is the function that programatically creates the `ListItems`

```
showResults : function(results) {

    results.forEach(function(result) {

        var li = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
            class : "linklist",
            href : "#",
            label : result.address,
            moveTo : "#",
            clickable : true,
            onClick : function() {
                console.log("click");
            }
        }, domConstruct.create("li", null, this.searchList));

        // dojo.connect(li, "click", lang.hitch(this, this.addResult, result))

    }, this);

}
```

I have tried providing the function with the `onClick` property in the constructor, as well as using `dojo.connect` after creation.  Neither way works.  I've also tried different variations of `click`, `onClick`, and `onclick`.

Any other posts that I have seen regarding this issue have suggested using the `dojo.connect` method commented above, but that is still not working for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does a pc browser show the same behaviour ?

Comment: Which version of dojo?

Comment: @LucianDepold - I am currently testing this in Chrome on my pc.

Comment: @PaulGrime - I am using dojo 1.8 via the ESRI Javascript API v 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your widget's startup() method is never called. You must either call li.startup() explicitly, or, instead of creating and passing a reference node to the ListItem constructor, you could use this.searchList.addChild(li) (this will also cause startup() to be called properly).

Comment: I tried the startup method and it still didn't work.  However, when I changed it to using `this.searchList.addChild(li)`, it did work.  Thanks for your help.  That one had me stumped.